# How to create a blank CSV file in iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, csv, nsfilemanager

I am trying to create a blank CSV file and then write to it using CHCSVWriter, but I do not see a method in the library to create a new file with no content. Is there something at the iOS level that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
NSString *content = @"content here";
NSData *fileContents = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"/my/path/to/file.csv"
                                contents:fileContents
                                attributes:nil];
```

if you want a blank file, try setting `contents:nil`